# Center div with left and right margins using boostrapt grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a div with less width than the container `col-lg-12`. This code works, but i have two empty divs only to create the margin. There is a better way to do this using bootstrap grid?

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <form role="form-horizontal" method="post">
            ...
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: To center a div just use col-lg-offset-2 in case for large screens and what you want for smaller screens. Offset just move to the right the div 2 columns

Comment: @PraveenKumar It's fair.

Comment: Thanks @user2990084! `:)`

Comment: Voted your question up! `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`offset`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) classes, also you have forgot giving a `.row` class before the *nested grids*:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
        <form role="form-horizontal" method="post">
         ...
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Make sure you give classes for all the media. Like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`offset` classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) provided by Bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
    <form role="form-horizontal" method="post">
      ...
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First, the answer is wrong. Second, it is a copy of mine.

Comment: So why you include col-lg-12 class in div with the same class?

Comment: I don't understand! Can you clarify?

Comment: Look at your code, you have col-lg-12 and below col-lg-8 - you have to have row before col-lg-8, not col-lg-12

Comment: Appreciated... Corrected it. `:)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92440/discussion-between-makshh-and-praveen-kumar).